# Get range substring from existing string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSString` and I want to make a substring from it, by locating a word.

For example, my string is: `@"text13 text12 text and new value"`
but when I will search "text" by programing,then it's returning range is 
range = location=0, length=4
but it should be return range of "text" string it means location 15 to lenth 4

```
NSString *string = @"text13 text12 text";
NSString *searchStr = @"text";
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchStr];
```

Can someone help me out or give me an example?

Thanks,
Sushil

Comment: You should say what describe your string, that is what are the separators allowed to define it a "text to be found". Spaces? Punctuations? Everithing else?

Comment: suppose that, if i will search "text", so i need range of same to same matching string, because here are text13 and text 13 , but i do not want range of this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized
                        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
     // this enumerate all the "words" of your string
     if ([string isEqualToString: searchString]) {
        // use substringRange, the range of your string
        // if you need only the first occurrence, then exit from block, otherwise continue
     }
}
```

Comment: Ahh! Thanking you muchly.its working fine, can you tell me one thing more?

Comment: suppose i have a string, string is @"hi this objective c \"i want to find ,this is substring\""; but i want find range of "i want to find ,this is substring", from total string only, i want to search by "" (double quote characacter)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undertand your question. Could you rephrase it, please?

Comment: This is my String :                                                                              NSString *string = @"hi this objective c and \"hello swift\""; but i want find range of  'hello swift' string, because it is simler one string(hello swift) inside other string.......  please help me

Comment: In this case I think you should simply search for the entire substring with the `rangeOfString` methods, not for words, as in my answer. Since the double quote is a character as any other in `string`, it should not produce any problem when searching in this way.